# incorrect dimensions for matrix multiplication in piecewise function in matlab

Tags: matlab

This is what I am trying to implement in Matlab:
[image]

Where `vi = sin(2*pi*1000*t)` and `VD = 0.72`.

These are my commands:

```
t = 1:1000;
t/1000;
vi = sin(2*pi*1000*t);
vo = piecewise(vi<0.72, 0, vi>0.72, (vi-0.72)*exp(-t));
```

However, I get this error: `Error using  *  Incorrect dimensions for matrix multiplication. Check that the number of columns in the first matrix matches the number of rows in the second matrix. To perform elementwise multiplication, use '.*'.`

I have no idea what I am doing wrong, any help?

Answer (score 0):

You problem is in the expression `(vi-0.72)*exp(-t)`.
Since `t` and `vi` are both matrices of size(1,1000), Matlab's `*` operator assumes you're trying to perform a ***matrix*** multiplication of a 1x1000 matrix by a 1x1000 matrix, which is not possible- hence the error.

You need to instead tell Matlab you want to multiply each element of `(vi-0.72)` by each element of `exp(-t)`, which you can do with `.*`.
So instead, your last line should be

```
>>> vo = piecewise(vi<0.72, 0, vi>0.72, (vi-0.72).*exp(-t))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues.

The first smaller issue is described in the answer by @Anthony Evans and details the difference between the `*` and `.*` operators.

The larger issue (and the reason why the supplied code still does not work - it returns an error relating to `piecewise`) is because the inputs to `piecewise` are supposed to be symbolic functions. If we see the usage on the [`piecewise` page](https://au.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sym.piecewise.html), before each use of the function `function`, we see creation of a new symbolic variable using the `syms` keyword.

As such, the best way to use `piecewise` would be by using a `symbolic` variable `t`, and noting that `vi` is a function (and so should be represented as a function handle). Then, we can use `piecewise`, and the outputs can be accessed using `subs`.

```
syms t; % symbolic variable
vi = @(x) sin(2*pi*1000*x); % function handle
vo = piecewise(vi(t)<0.72, 0, vi(t)>0.72, (vi(t)-0.72).*exp(-t)); % also returns a function
figure; plot(0:1e-5:1e-2, subs(vo, t, 0:1e-5:1e-2)); % access data using plot
figure; fplot(vo); % another example visualisation
```